# can't get bottom:0; to work on my button

Tags: html, css

I need a button at the bottom of the page.
Normally i would use the bottom tag (parent div relative position and child div absolute position etc) but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

The first DIV is the exact size of the browser window (I found this code online) and I think that's why I can't get the button to the bottom.
When I trie to change the CSS of the first div it doesn't work properly, so if anyone knows what to do without changing the first div that would help.

The website is http://www.nickyvanbuuren.com/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I just added `position:absolute` in your `#knop`

Answer (score -1):

In your source code the `#knop` doesn't have `position:absolute;` assigned to it.

I have changed it in below example, and the `bottom:0;` is now being triggered:

```
#knop {
  -webkit-animation: mover 2s infinite alternate;
  animation: mover 2s infinite alternate;
  width: 21px;
  height: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Although please edit your question and post the example code, so future visitors have some reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I know it was a bit blunt to ask the question like that, I couldn't figure out how to display the HTML and CSS like you did above... but I will edit it for future visitors. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Your `#knop` was missing a `position: absolute`

```
#knop {
    -webkit-animation: mover 2s infinite alternate;
    animation: mover 2s infinite alternate;
    width: 21px;
    height: 12px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 980px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also if you add `width: 980px` and `text-align: center` your button will be centered horizontally

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thank you so much!